# Do words have names?

Tags: grammar

## I was wondering.

A word can be a verb, adjective, adverb, noun, etc. Is a word its own name? So the word “jump” (verb). Is it also a noun?, but only for the very special case of naming itself.

---

## Why I was thinking this.

I was explaining to a colleague, how to name parts of a computer program (variables, functions, procedures, etc). I stated that procedures should be verb phrases; functions and variables that are boolean should be adjectives, and functions and variables that are not boolean should be nouns. We did not get to adverbs (that is lesson two).

My colleague said that because they are names (variable name, function name etc), then they should all be nouns. This got me thinking. There must be something wrong about what we were taught at school (no surprise there).

Comment: `"teach"` is a noun.  `teach` is a verb.

Comment: @HotLicks are you saying that the quotes, turn it into its own name?

Comment: When you use quotes, in any reasonably conventional sense (or speak of words in a fashion where they would be quoted if written down), the quoted text functions as a noun, losing it's previous part-of-speech role.

Comment: This might be better on [linguistics] or [philosophy] . Computer programs are different, they depend on the language. Traditional imperative languages tend to have variables that are like nouns and procedures which are like verbs. But in functional languages procedures are objects like nouns and variables are just functions with no arguments. So it depends. But this isn't English, it's programming language theory. In English, nouns are nouns, verbs are verbs. The word 'verb' is a noun, and likewise 'noun' is a noun (and all the other labels 
 of parts of speech).

Comment: This is in programming, so we can not italicise, or quote. However I think that we have answered my question: Yes. a variable/function/procedure name does not have to be a noun. Functions/variables returning non-boolean are nouns-phrases e.g. `height` , Functions/variables returning boolean are adjective-phrases e.g. `is_on`, procedures are verbs `switch on`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is the use-mention distinction.
Your 'naming itself' notion is described as a *mention*.

> The **use–mention distinction** is a foundational concept of analytic
>   philosophy, according to which it is necessary to make a distinction
>   between *using* a word (or phrase) and *mentioning* it, and many
>   philosophical works have been "vitiated by a failure to distinguish
>   use and mention". The distinction is disputed by non-analytic
>   philosophers.
>
> The distinction between use and mention can be illustrated for the
>   word *cheese*:
>
> - *Use*: Cheese is derived from milk.
> - *Mention*: 'Cheese' is derived from the Old English word *ċēse*.
>
> The first sentence is a statement about the substance called "cheese";
>   it *uses* the word 'cheese' to refer to that substance. The second is
>   a statement about the word 'cheese' as a signifier; it *mentions* the
>   word without using it to refer to anything other than itself.
>
> [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction)

When you deal with, say, a *function name* `get()`, you need to distinguish between the use of that name and the mention of that name. Since you *use* `get()` to *do* something, it makes sense to pick a verb as the name. When you say that `get()` is a function name, you aren't using the function; you're just *mentioning* it.

Comment: Further, it's important to not pick a name which might, should it lose its immediate context, lead one astray, due to this "use-mention" thing and related issues.  I can't think of any good examples offhand, but I've seen many.

Comment: I think you mean procedure. A function returns a value and is a noun(non-boolean) or adjective(boolean). A procedure does something (verb). Most people make this mistake. I think this may be why some started using the word method (Maybe).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor - Depends on the computer language.  There are some that have no "functions", others that have no "procedures".

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I was focusing on use/mention and used the term *function* generically. A lot of functions are named after verbs or verb phrases - 'getters' are a good example of this. Even boolean functions are often named `is_xyz()`, which has the *verb* to be 'is' at its head. The way the function is used also comes into play. If you want to say `d = door_of(room)`, it makes sense to not use a verb.

Comment: As for formatting when it comes to this, here's what *The Chicago Manual of Style* (7.63) says: "When a word or term is not used functionally but is referred to as the word or term itself, it is either italicized or enclosed in quotation marks. . . . Although italics are the traditional choice, quotation marks may be more appropriate in certain contexts."

Comment: @Lawrence `is_xyz` is an adjective phrase, made of is (verb) and `xyz`. And `get_xyz` is a bad choice for a function, this is what I was trying to explain to my work colleague. We don't say “get do you want fries with that?” or “What is the get height of the tree?”

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I'm no linguist, but wouldn't an *adjective phrase* be [headed by an adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective_phrase) rather than a [verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb_phrase)? I have mixed feelings about *getters*: they can be awkwardly named in the manner you pointed out and are often unnecessary, but consistency also has its place in naming. I have more to say on the topic (though our views on it are fundamentally quite close, I think), but we're starting to drift afield of the site's scope, so I'll stop here rather than chance drawing the ire of the mods.

Comment: @Lawrence I am not a linguist either. However I remember that a grammar tree has words (nouns, adjectives, verbs, etc.) as its leafs, and each non-leaf node (made of other nodes) is also a noun, adjective, verb. A definition of a verb is any word that can be preceded by `is` e.g. `is hot`, `is tall`, and a noun is any word that can be proceeded by `the` e.g. `the happiness`, and a verb any word that can be proceeded by `to` e.g. `to run`, `to jump`

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Hmm ... the "to run/jump" parts looks ok, but the earlier part doesn't sound right. In "is X" (e.g. is *hot*), in the simple case, X describes a noun, so X should be called an adjective, not a verb. Verbs can be thought of in the first instance as things the noun *does*, not things the noun *is*. E.g. in the sentence "After the run, the runner was hot.", *runner* is a noun, *run* is a verb, and *hot* is an adjective that describes the (noun) *runner*.

Comment: @Lawrence sorry it seems that I made an error, that you spotted. Note I say that the adjectives are verbs, and I say that the verbs are verbs. I don't have edit permission on comments, so can not fix.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor No problem. Shall we delete some of the comments?